# cx_freeze application not working on a different computer

Tags: python, tkinter, cx-freeze

Have created an application using cx_freeze which runs with no issues on my own system but shows the error message shown in the image when the application is downloaded onto a different computer. It looks like its trying to look into my local system rather than the lib file for the modules and don't know how to change that. Have put my setup script below as well.

[image]

setup.py

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

includefiles = ['plankton (1).png', 'white_down_arrow.png','white_up_arrow.png','plankton150Model/', 'plankton_icon.ico']

base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

setup(
    name="Plankton Classifier",
    version="0.1",
    description="Plankton Classifier",
    options= {'build_exe': {'include_files':includefiles}},
    executables=[Executable("original_custom_tk.py", base=base)],
)
```

Comment: first put error as text - so we could select and copy text. You can open console and run .exe in console to see and select text.

Comment: Python wasn't created to build exe programs - so `cx_freeze`, `pyinstaller` and similar programs may have problem to find all needed Python modules and C/C++ libraries and you may have to add them manually in `setup.py`

Comment: @furas I've checked the lib folder to cx_freeze creates and all the libraries and all the files mentioned in the error message are in there. But on all of them the file location it's looking for them in is from my local system which is why it has Olly in it but this was run on a different computer so I don't understand why its looking there rather than in the lib files that cx_freeze creates